# ORDER BY clause with 2 parameters

Tags: parameters, sql-order-by, clause

I need to find a solution for using 2 parameters in order by clause, one for the columns and one for ascending, descending.
Both parameters are as input in a procedure.

[...]
ORDER BY @column @sortDirection
[...]

The issue is that ORDER BY apparently does not support this unless I specify only one column name and one direction name (not as params ?)

We have a solution using a query string and executing that inside procedure but I need to find another solution so the text is easy to read and follow.

Right now, I am trying using CASE inside the ORDER BY:
Syntax is accepted but not sorting.
[...]
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @column = 'ABC' THEN 'ABC'
WHEN @column = 'XYZ' THEN 'XYZ'
END
+ ' ' +
CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ASC
WHEN @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN DESC
END
[...]

Any suggestions to fix this or other method ?

Comment: You need to specify what database you are using and what language you are coding in. Is this a stored procedure?

Comment: Using SQL Server DB and yes, it is a stored procedure.